# Cookies not saved in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using rails 6.0 in a new project and after that cookies are not set

```rb
 Include ActionDispatch::Cookies 
 Include ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore 
  before_action :cookie_set
  def cookie_set
    cookies[:test] = {value: 'testset'}
  end
```

browser cookie is empty

Comment: Do you use Turbolinks?

Comment: No. i'm use api only mode

Comment: and you call it via javascript? I am not sure, if browser updates displayed cookies (at least safari doesn't) if they are changed via AJAX, but if you reload the page, browser will show the cookies.

Comment: no. i'm call it via http request with reload

Comment: can you post your code, how you call the rails API?

Comment: i'm call rails api in browser, GET request without js, through address bar. code updated in question

Comment: Cookies are a concept in the context of browsers. Enabling Rails' API mode removes the necessary `ActionDispatch::Cookies` and `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` middlewares from the application.

Comment: These modules  is Included, thx for answers

Comment: That is not how you add middlewares to the rack stack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use your Rails application on api mode some middlewares that are needed to make cookies work are not included by default. To enable them maintaining api mode, edit your  `config/application.rb` by adding:

```
# Stuff you application needs
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
  config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_namespace_key'
# Maybe more stuff...
end
```